# Ma Inyan Shmitta Eitzel Har Sinai?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, shmita, behar

[Rashi](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?AID=15585&p=1&v=ds) says

> What does the subject of Shemittah have with Mount Sinai? Were not all the commandments stated from Sinai? However, [this teaches us that] just as with Shemittah, its general principles and its finer details were all stated from Sinai, likewise, all of them were stated-their general principles [together with] their finer details-from Sinai.

Yet, in all other mitzvos (Shabbos, for example), one who violates a Tolda of an Aveira has still Biblically violated that Aveira. However, one who violates a Tolda of Shmitta [did not](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/7701.htm).

What does Rashi mean?

Comment: Only punishable derabanan, but maybe still assur deorayta. And maybe not. We would have to check somehow.

Comment: That's all part of the "general principles [together with] their finer details". At Sinai all the details of the laws of Shemita were told, including the fact that only specific Tuldot are punishable.

Comment: Shmuel Brin, I'm not following how your question is related to Rashi.

Comment: @YDK how is it "Keshem"?

Comment: Rashi's point is that no mitzvos nor their details were given as an addendum to the Torah, all were given from Sinai.  I don't understand how that relates to whether there is an onesh on a tolada.

Comment: Rashi means something like the Rambam's introduction to Mishneh Torah: *All the commandments that were given to Moshe at Sinai were given together with their interpretation, as it is written "and I will give thee the Tables of Stone, and the Law, and the Commandment" (Exodus 24,12).  "Law" is the Written Law; and "Commandment" is its interpretation:  We were commanded to fulfill the Law, according to the Commandment.  And this Commandment is what is called the Oral Law.*